# PUT failing in curl for database

Tags: curl

I am trying to input data into a database. Using the JSON information directly works perfectly fine, but once I use a JSON file path, I am returned an error which states UTF-8 JSON error. I tried using charset UTF-8 in my header, but realized it was not needed since application/x-www-form-urlencoded was already included.

```
curl -v -X PUT 'http://adminstrator:password@db:5984/data/_design/somedesign' --data-binary '@json/views/someDesign.json'
```

If I replace @json/views/someDesign.json with just JSON, it completes.

```
curl -X PUT 'http://administrator:password@db:5984/data/_design/somedesign' --data-binary '{"id":"0"}'
(EXAMPLE)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try `@'file'` instead of `'@file'`

Comment: also run `printf '{"id":"0"}' | b2sum` then run `cat 'json/views/someDesign.json' | b2sum`, does the 2 sums look identical or are they completely different?

Comment: @hanshenrik Hey hanshenrik, thanks for the help buddy. I just tried the first recommendation and that still gave me an UTF-8 error. As for the second one, the output for the working curl command outputted as usual; however, the second outputted 'could not resolve host json'